# Restore document with embedded documents on ODM

Tags: php, mongodb, json, doctrine-odm

Here are two sample classes I have:

```
/** @ODM\Document */
class Product implements JsonSerializable{

  /** @ODM\String */
  protected $some_property;

  /** @ODM\EmbedMany */
  protected $attributes;

  public function jsonSerialize(){
    $o = new StdClass();
    $o->property = $this->some_property;
    $o->attributes = $this->attributes;
    return $o;
  }
}

/** @ODM\EmbeddedDocument */
class Attribute implements JsonSerializable{

  /** @ODM\String */
  protected $some_property;

  public function jsonSerialize(){
    $o = new StdClass();
    $o->property = $this->some_property;
    return $o;
  }
}
```

In my code, I create an instance of Product, and then some processes create an array of Attribute instances on `$product->attributes`.
I persist the Product instance without a problem into mongoDB using Doctrine ODM.
I can go into the DB (using rockmongo), and I see the presisted document, and the annotations on the JSON view to the class of the `attributes` array:

```
"_doctrine_class_name": "\Attribute"
```

But when I query for that product using the QueryBuilder, instead of getting an array of Attribute instances, I get a PersistentCollection (looking at the isntance with the debugger at runtime).

I believe this has to do with *lazy loading*, but its breaking up my code.
When I try to call `json_encode($product)`, instead of cascading through to each of the `Attribtue` instances, it just returns an empty array.

Here is what I expect to get form a json_encode():

```
{
    "property": "some product value",
    "attributes": [
        {
            "property": "some attribute value"
        },
        {
            "property": "some attribute value"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to either disable *lazy loading*, or force the proper instantiation of each Attribute instance?
Or any other way to be able to get the desired JSON object, without having to manually traversing the whole structure?
Thanks!

Comment: What about not using Doctrine ODM but just raw php Mongo ?

Comment: Well... not much of a solution to the problem, since to be homogeneous I'd need to restructure the project.
But what do you mean by raw php Mongo, and where can I read some tutorials or doc for that (specific in ZF2)?

Comment: I agree, it's not a solution. But IMO you are trying to use the ODM features for working with an kind of dynamic array. If I am right, this is straightforward with [\MongoClient](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongoclient.php) or [\MongoCollection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongocollection.php) as you are working directly with an array. And you can access it through doctrine-odm like this `$documentManager->getConnection()->getMongo()`. Not sure that help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I ended up solving the issue of lazy-loading:

```
// parent jsonSerialize method
public function jsonSerialize(){
  $o = new StdClass();
  $o->property = $this->some_property;
  $a = [];
  foreach($this->attributes as $attr){
    $a[] = $attr;
  }
  $o->attributes = $a;
  return $o;
}
```

This forces the PersistentCollection object to spit our one by one the proper instances, and then the jsonSerializable methods respond well cascaded through.

Ugly IMO, but solves the issue. Sadly, you have to apply this on every Embedded Object dependency you have.

Hole it helps!

Comment: Dude, I was looking for that solution! But what I don't understand: What is the intention of ODM to let us doing that ugly thing? Are we doing it wrong? How is it supposed to be correctly?

Comment: Another, more clean solutions would be to do 
`$o->attributes = $this->attributes->toArray()`
instead of the manual for loop. But feels ugly anyway.